# Any AppWidgetHost-tutorials out there?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I'm writing an application that should both have the ability to place widgets on the home screen, and to show these widgets in the application itself. I figure that the best way to do this is through the use of an AppWidgetHost for the application part.

I've been looking around, but I cannot find any good examples on how to write AppWidgetHosts. Have any of you done this, and are willing to share? Or do you know of any tutorials that I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly a tutorial but here is an older forum [post](http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/appwidgethost-tutorial-t10329.html).

The code is part of the [mylock](http://code.google.com/p/mylockforandroid/) project, which you also might find useful if you dig.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've seen that one, and that it didn't seem to be complete. I will glimpse through the source, and see if I can make any sense of it :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, esp for the first link, sir!