# how can i put widgets and shortcuts on viewpager's page?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I have implemented a`ViewPager`in my customize home Launcher application and I added 5 pages in the`ViewPager`.

Now I want to add home screen widgets and application shortcuts on individual pages in my`ViewPager`. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar question (in part about Widgets): [Any AppWidgetHost-tutorials out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894489/any-appwidgethost-tutorials-out-there)

And [here](http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/appwidgethost-tutorial-t10329.html) is an AppWidgetHost tutorial with a mostly working example. At least it's a good starting point.

**Note:** there is a misprint in line 176 of the example:

```
int appWidgetId = WidgetScreen.this.mAppWidgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId();
```

should be replaced by

```
int appWidgetId = mAppWidgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId();
```